# Why are there Fully-Modular PSUs?

Tags: power-supply

I understand the point of Semi-Modular, but with Fully-Modular you really have to attach cables you'd be required to use! Is it only a moneymaking scheme, or is there a point to getting one?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This [FAQ on the NZXT website](http://support.nzxt.com/hc/en-us/articles/202798380-Full-Vs-Semi-Vs-Non-Modular-What-Are-The-Differences-) focuses on the cabling issue. Fully-modular = less cables and less cables = improved airflow and simplified cable management.

> Comes with no cables pre-attached. You only attach the ones you need.
>
> It is more expensive, but also gives you more options, allowing you to
>   only install the cables you need and keep airflow and cable management
>   to a maximum. All newer generation HALE PSUs are fully modular.

Also remember from, from a marketing point of view, a manufacturer who is selling equipment to systems customizers assumes that:

1. The person building the system might have a cache of their own cables lying around.
2. Anyone into system customizing at that level will just spend more and more without caring much about cost.

In the great scheme of things, there are two broad types of people building systems from the ground up: Those looking for a bargain and those who will just throw money at a “hobby” system. Nowadays since most people prefer to buy pre-built systems and customizers just see it as a long-term “fun” hobby. A money conscious person in 2015 is not building a PC from scratch.

Comment: But why no 20+4 or CPU connector?

Answer (score 1):

Aesthetics. You're almost certainly going to *need* the standard 20+4 connector, and ATX power. However, a fully modular cable means you can buy suitable connectors or entire cables custom cabling in colour, sheathing and layout of your choice. You could choose not to have the standard colour/voltage coded layout for example, and have a bright pink case with UV reactive cables, something that would require you to essentially chop a regular PSU apart.

For a less extreme example, you could build something like this with a consistant colour scheme

[image]
([randomly found on google here](http://www.overclock.net/t/1288039/sleeved-cable-color-example-gallery-and-color-suggestion-thread/200))

Its all about the looks.